# Issue to use GitHub Copilot

Tags: php, github, phpstorm, github-copilot

i build a project in laravel with vuejs , i tried to add github Copilot in the PhpStorm , but after i download the copilot and try to login in github , i cant and get this error in phpstorm , any ideea how i can solve it  :

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.intellij.ui.dsl.builder.Row com.intellij.ui.dsl.builder.Panel.row$default(com.intellij.ui.dsl.builder.Panel, javax.swing.JLabel, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object)'
> at com.github.copilot.github.DeviceLoginForm.descriptionPanel(DeviceLoginForm.kt:60)
> at com.github.copilot.github.DeviceLoginForm.access$descriptionPanel(DeviceLoginForm.kt:18)
> at com.github.copilot.github.DeviceLoginForm$deviceLoginPanel$container$1.invoke(DeviceLoginForm.kt:29)
> at com.github.copilot.github.DeviceLoginForm$deviceLoginPanel$container$1.invoke(DeviceLoginForm.kt:27)
> at com.intellij.ui.dsl.builder.BuilderKt.panel(builder.kt:19)
> at com.github.copilot.ui.component.Panel.panelBuilder(Panel.kt:9)
> at com.github.copilot.github.DeviceLoginForm.deviceLoginPanel(DeviceLoginForm.kt:27)
> at com.github.copilot.github.DeviceLoginForm.(DeviceLoginForm.kt:22)
> at com.github.copilot.github.DeviceLoginDialog.createCenterPanel(DeviceLoginDialog.java:65)
> at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.init(DialogWrapper.java:1308)
> at com.github.copilot.github.DeviceLoginDialog.showDeviceLogin(DeviceLoginDialog.java:30)
> at com.github.copilot.lang.agent.AgentGitHubService.loginInteractive(AgentGitHubService.java:108)
> at com.github.copilot.actions.LoginToGitHubAction.actionPerformed(LoginToGitHubAction.java:18)
> at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.doPerformActionOrShowPopup(ActionUtil.java:315)
> at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.lambda$performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks$4(ActionUtil.java:294)
> at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:337)
> at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:294)
> at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$performAction$4(ActionMenuItem.java:293)
> at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:227)
> at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.performAction(ActionMenuItem.java:286)
> at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$new$0(ActionMenuItem.java:67)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
> at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$3(ActionMenuItem.java:109)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:94)
> at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:109)
> at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:546)
> at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:578)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6648)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3392)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6413)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5022)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2802)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:781)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:730)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:754)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:752)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:751)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:918)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:840)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:763)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:450)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:791)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:624)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:447)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:881)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:493)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)

i already look to update both plugin and phpstorm and restart the phpstorm , can somebody help me out to solve this issue?
Authenticated GitHub Copilot with my GitHub user and password.
Allowed GitHub Copilot in GitHub account profile.
Restarted the IDE multiple times after the plugin installation.
I have license for Github Copilot.

Comment: i think your github copilot is not authenticated. You've to create a separate SSH for PHP Storm in your github account.